# Why did the Akatsuki wait for 3 years before resuming their mission of gathering the Tailed Beasts?

Tags: naruto

After Shikamaru's team failed to bring back Sasuke, the Akatsuki members were shown for the first time and they waited for 3 years before resuming their mission. Why did they wait?

Comment: Probably because they were gathering information about who the jinchuurikis are. They probably has known that Gaara is the Ichibi, Killer B is the Hachibi and Naruto is the Kyuubi, but probably has no idea about who the rest of the jinchuurikis are as some of the jinchuuriki live a secluded live, like Utakata the Rokubi and the Yonbi old man

Answer (score 1):

They didn't paused there mission and resumed it later but they continued it behind the curtains. They have to capture tailed beast by an order and Naruto falls in last number and then they needed preparation too for sealing beats and location ensuring etc. They also had non-trustable member to deal with and maybe some other background stuff behind the curtains.

Comment: why did they have to follow specific order?